# Generated JSON Schema does not show properties of fields that are of type 'object'

Tags: spring-data-rest, jsonschema

The JSON schema generated by spring-data-rest does not contain definitions of properties that are of type 'object'.

I'm trying to use the generated schema to automatically create a form using uniforms-material/AutoForm. It needs the definition of these object properties to create the form correctly.

```
curl localhost:8080/api/profile/agentContactRecords -H 
"Accept:application/schema+json"
```

I expect the output of the above schema request to be

```
...
"Agent Business Lines" : {
  "title" : "Agent business lines",
  "type" : "array",
  "items" : {
    "type" : "object",
          "properties": {
            "Business Line": {
              "type": "string",
              "title": "The Business line Schema"
            },
            "Agent Name": {
              "type": "string",
              "title": "The Agent name Schema"
            }
          }
  }
},
"Agent" : {
  "title" : "Agent",
  "type" : "object",
          "properties": {
            "Agent Number": {
              "type": "string",
              "title": "The Agent number Schema"
            }
          }
},
...
```

But I get the following

```
...
"Agent Business Lines" : {
  "title" : "Agent business lines",
  "readOnly" : false,
  "type" : "array",
  "items" : {
    "type" : "object"
  }
},
"Agent" : {
  "title" : "Agent",
  "readOnly" : false,
  "type" : "object"
},
...
```

Comment: OK. This sounds like an issue with a specific library. I suggest you log an issue in the appropriate issue tracker for that library.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is an additional feature request for a specific library or implementation

Answer (score 0):

I checked the source code for PersistentEntityToJsonSchemaConverter.java in Spring Darta Rest and found that it does not determine the properties of the items (of type object) inside an array-property.

> I found a way to extend this class and add this functionality by
>   extending the RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration class and it's method
>   jsonSchemaConverter.
>   Unfortunately there is no way to extend the JsonSchema class because it uses a package scoped object(AbstractJsonSchemaProperty) in it's constructor.

Answer (score 0):

The object property within my entity was annotated with @ElementCollection(targetClass="className.class"). However the targetClass itself was annotated with @Entity annotation. When I changed the target class to instead be a plain java object (no @Entity annotation), the fields started appearing in the json schema with the property $ref as shown below.

```
    "agentBusinessLines" : {
      "title" : "Agent business lines",
      "readOnly" : false,
       "type" : "array",
      "items" : {
        "$ref" : "#/definitions/agentBusinessLineNonEntityCopy"
      }
    },
  "definitions" : {
    "agentBusinessLineNonEntityCopy" : {
      "type" : "object",
  "properties" : {
    "businessLineAcronym" : {
      "title" : "Business line acronym",
      "readOnly" : false,
      "type" : "string"
    },
    "agentName" : {
      "title" : "Agent name",
      "readOnly" : false,
      "type" : "string"
    },
    "company" : {
      "title" : "Company",
      "readOnly" : false,
      "type" : "string"
    },
    "agentNumber" : {
      "title" : "Agent number",
      "readOnly" : false,
      "type" : "integer"
    }
  }
}
```